# Create a file and write data to it

Tags: shell, jenkins-cli

I am very new to jenkins and shell scripting. I am working on a task where i have to create a file and write $[Orance.home] in it.Please let me know is there any command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be missing something, but you could do

```
# replace MY_FILE.txt content with one line containing ${Orance.home}
echo "${Orance.home}" > MY_FILE.txt
```

or possibly,

```
# Append ${Orance.home} to MY_FILE.txt
echo "${Orance.home}" >> MY_FILE.txt
```

Or, you might use the [tee command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) (with our without `-a`)

```
echo "${Orance.home}" | tee MY_FILE.txt
```

Comment: if i want to append text to next line in the same file hows that possible

Comment: Use `>>` instead of `>`; or `tee -a`.